# Только желтый флажок на open server

Tags: openserver

когда нажимаю запустить open server доходит только до желтого флажка и все, обратно красный! Что может быть не так? .-.

Comment: Может версия БД не совместима с версией PHP или апачем.

Comment: @entithat а как проверить?

Comment: Скорей всего у тебя php и apache несовместимых версий, попробуй поставить одинаковую в разделе Настройки - Модули

Comment: Изменил mysql на более новую и заработало. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Занят порт HTTPS, измени в "Настройки(Сервер)" его с 443 на, к примеру, 442 и всё будет работать

Comment: изменил, 2 раза, не хочет